# ListView (Adapter) item visibility listener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Is it possible to have a visibility listener on each listview's item? Like: on user sees the item, do something. On item is hidden, do something else.

I want to check when a item "enters" or "exits" the scroll so as to update a second list.

Additionaly my ListView might expand like:

```
adapter.addAll(  (Collection<? extends DBObject>) events);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think a way might be to use a global listener to check the items but I am afraid it will get messed up if I add more items to the ListView (above). I have not accomplished anything with that yet

```
eventList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the onScroll function to calculate that.

```
eventList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    int oldFirstVisibleItem = 0;
    int oldLastVisibleItem = 0;

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (firstVisibleItem > oldFirstVisibleItem) {
            for(int i = oldFirstVisibleItem; i < firstVisibleItem; i++) {
                onExit(i);
            }
        }
        if (firstVisibleItem < oldFirstVisibleItem) {
            for(int i = firstVisibleItem; i < oldFirstVisibleItem; i++) {
                onEnter(i);
            }
        }

        int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount - 1;
        if (lastVisibleItem < oldLastVisibleItem) {
            for(int i = oldLastVisibleItem+1; i <= lastVisibleItem; i++) {
                onExit(i);
            }
        } 
        if (lastVisibleItem > oldLastVisibleItem) {
            for(int i = oldLastVisibleItem+1; i <= lastVisibleItem; i++) {
                onEnter(i);
            }
        } 

        oldFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        oldLastVisibleItem = lastVisibleItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
});

public void onEnter(int position) {
    // Handle an item coming into view.
}

public void onExit(int position) {
    // Handle an item going out of view.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question.

One of the methods that you override in the onScrollListener() is

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
```

The parameters passed include the `firstVisibleItem`, and the `visibleItemCount`. you can use these two numbers to figure out which items are currently visible.

Just keep in mind that onScroll is called very often while scrolling.